# How to check if a button contains an emoji with the customID - Discord JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Can someone help me to find a solution to my problem? I want to check if a `Button` contains an emoji with the `customId`.

For example, Button x has `customId` 1 & `emoji` . I want to check with the help of the `customId` 1 if the `emoji` is .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you receive the `interaction`, the button is found inside the `interaction.message`.

You had to create a `MessageActionRow` sent in an array. This [`MessageActionRowComponent`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/MessageActionRowComponent) will be the first item in `message.components`. Then, you used `addComponents()` to add the button to that row, so that [`MessageButton`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageButton) will be the first item in that `component`.

It means, your button is:

```js
interaction.message.components[0].components[0]
```

If you've sent your button in a different way, you'll need to adjust those indexes above.

So, once you have your button, you can use its [`emoji`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageButton?scrollTo=emoji) property to get the emoji used. This emoji object has a `name` property that holds the emoji sent.

You can find an example below.

If you send the button with the emoji like this...

```js
client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;

  let row = new MessageActionRow();

  row.addComponents(
    new MessageButton().setCustomId('1').setStyle('SECONDARY').setEmoji(''),
  );

  message.channel.send({
    content: '⬇ Click it, click it, click it! ⬇',
    components: [row],
  });
});
```

You can use the following to handle the interaction and to check the `emoji` and the `customId`:

```js
client.on('interactionCreate', (interaction) => {
  if (!interaction.isButton()) return;

  let { customId } = interaction;
  let row = interaction.message.components[0];
  let button = row.components[0];

  if (customId === '1' && button.emoji.name === '')
    interaction.reply(
      `The button you clicked has the custom id of _"${customId}"_ and the "${button.emoji.name}" emoji`,
    );
  else interaction.reply('Oops, maybe a different button?!');
});
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks you man (My last comment didn't get send)